# how can I get the right query with if(isset($GET[' user'] and if empty user in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I use this query to get username data table so if i write url `index.php?user=username` get user data base on username if index.php and data table redirect to admin table this my query 
it's work if i write url `index.php?user=username` data display base on username but if write index.php data not display ..

what wrong with this query thanks

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])) {
  $result = mysql_query("select * from content_table where username = '" . $_GET['user'] . "' limit 2 ;");
if(!empty($GET['user'])){
  $result = mysql_query("select * from content_table order by content_id desc limit 1;");
}
```

Comment: You're wide open to sql injections

Comment: Close the brace properly and check

Comment: You have the test backwards. You want to do the general query when the variable is empty, not when it's NOT emptyl.

Comment: i'm new and i'm just learn how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(empty($GET['user'])){
  $result = mysql_query("select * from content_table order by content_id desc limit 1;");
}

if(isset($_GET['user'])) {
  $result = mysql_query("select * from content_table where username = '" . $_GET['user'] . "' limit 2 ;");
```

Comment: What if the variable set to the empty string?

Comment: if i use your query when i type index.php?user=username the result display all username and when i type index.php no result was display

Comment: @barmar if mysql_query(won't) execute multiple table .. can i redirect to another location for example redirect to index2.php thanks

Comment: @Zein Yes, you can redirect. That has nothing to do with mysql.

Comment: how can i add if user no in table and echo no username ?

Comment: what you mean your question?

Comment: i mean if user type a wrong username example if in table no test1 name and page will redirect with message no user name with that name example when type a wrong user url _index.php?user=test1_ and that test1 name no in table the page will show no username for test1

Comment: what you do further process if user exist and if user does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the SQL injection issue aside for now. First of all, you are missing a closing curly brace. The second problem is that you are not doing the second part correctly.  You have:

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])) {
    // query based on username
if(!empty($GET['user'])){
    // query just first row
}
```

The second check is doing the same as the first one - there's no need for it.  Your logic should be:

```
if(!empty($_GET['user'])) {
    // query based on username
}
else {
    // query just first row
}
```

Note that you will also need to deal with empty results somewhere.

Now, as for your SQL injection vulnerability, imagine for a second that the username passed in is `myname'; drop table content_table --` - your code would simply put this in and execute it - dropping the table.  Think about it.

Oh, and please do yourself a favour and stop using `mysql_` functions - switch to PDO or at least `mysqli_`.

Comment: `mysql_query` won't execute multiple queries, so the SQL injection example won't actually drop anything.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it a zillion times. There are other APIs that will allow you to execute multiple queries in a single call, I can only assume that's what Bobby's school uses.

Comment: @Bamar It wasn't specifically a reply to your comment, rather to the OP's question :)

Answer (score 0):

You have your `empty` test backwards. So when the parameter is empty, you never perform either query.

Do this:

```
if (empty($_GET['user'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("select * from content_table order by content_id desc limit 1;");
} else {
    $result = mysql_query("select * from content_table where username = '" . $_GET['user'] . "' limit 2 ;");
}
```

`empty()` performs an `isset` test first, so you don't need to do both.

Comment: i have this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a close brace